# 'Generic DOM scraper using DOMDocument and cURL' error after upgrading to PHP8.1

Tags: php, variables, curl, dom

I have been using a DOM scraper code for some years (I can not remember where I got it).
After upgrading from PHP7.4 to PHP8.1 (finally) it stopped working with the following error code:

```
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Argument #1 ($source) must not be empty
```

As I see it the variable is never empty. I am running this code within a module in Joomla 3.10, Apache, Linux. I also use this same code in another file, that is run from CLI with a cronjob (for a different purpose). And that seems to be working just fine. But run from the browser it does not seem to work anymore.
What is the problem here? And how can I fix it? This is the scraper code:

```
// acquire data
$source = 'https://www.somesite.com/category/somepage';
$scraper = new DOMScraper();
$scraper->setSite($source)->setSource();
echo $scraper->getInnerHTML('table');

/**
 * Generic DOM scraper using DOMDocument and cURL
 */
Class DOMScraper extends DOMDocument{
    public $site;
    private $source;
    private $dom;

    function __construct(){
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $this->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $this->strictErrorChecking = false;
    }

    function setSite($site){
        $this->site = $site;
        return $this;
    }

    function setSource(){
        if(empty($this->site))return 'Error: Missing $this->site, use setSite() first';
        $this->source = $this->get_data($this->site);
        return $this;
    }

    function getInnerHTML($tag, $id=null, $nodeValue = false){
        if(empty($this->site))return 'Error: Missing $this->source, use setSource() first';
        $this->loadHTML($this->source);
        $tmp = $this->getElementsByTagName($tag);
        $ret = null;
        foreach ($tmp as $v){
            if($id !== null){
                $attr = explode('=',$id);
                if($v->getAttribute($attr[0])==$attr[1]){
                    if($nodeValue == true){
                        $ret .= trim($v->nodeValue);
                    }else{
                        $ret .= $this->innerHTML($v);
                    }
                }
            }else{
                if($nodeValue == true){
                    $ret .= trim($v->nodeValue);
                }else{
                    $ret .= $this->innerHTML($v);
                }
            }
        }
        return $ret;
    }

    function innerHTML($dom){
        $ret = "";
        $nodes = $dom->childNodes;
        foreach($nodes as $v){
            $tmp = new DOMDocument();
            $tmp->appendChild($tmp->importNode($v, true));
            $ret .= trim($tmp->saveHTML());
        }
        return $ret;
    }

    function get_data($url){
        if(function_exists('curl_init')){
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $data;
        }else{
            return file_get_contents($url);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first line to `getInnerHTML` appears wrong, it should be `if(empty($this->source))`

Comment: Indeed you are right. Never noticed that. Fatal error now gone and script can run under php 8.